# Why I am not able to open camera from webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

I am having problem that I am not able to open camera from webview in that I am having php page so I have to open gallery and camera from there but I am not able to do what I got from this link "https://gist.github.com/jhonsore/8a8378c147ec00ac6f3fa53569c82ef8".
I can open gallery but not camera please give me any solution.

Answer (score 4):

A working example in Kotlin for Android 7+

Add camera permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
```

Configure your `WebView`

```
private fun configureWebViewSettings() {
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.setSupportZoom(false)
    binding.webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    binding.webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
    binding.webView.webChromeClient = getCustomWebChromeClient()
}
```

Add the lines below to your `Activity`

```
private var imagePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null
private var cameraImagePath: String? = null
```

Implement a `WebChromeClient` and add it to your `WebView`

```
    private fun getCustomWebChromeClient() = object : WebChromeClient() {
    
        override fun onShowFileChooser(
            view: WebView?,
            filePath: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
            fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
        ): Boolean {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    
            imagePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
            imagePathCallback = null
            imagePathCallback = filePath
    
            val takePictureIntent = createImageCaptureIntent()
    
            val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            contentSelectionIntent.type = INTENT_FILE_TYPE
    
            val intentArray: Array<Intent?>
            intentArray = takePictureIntent?.let { arrayOf(it) } ?: arrayOfNulls(0)
    
            val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.file_chooser_title))
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)
    
            try {
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                imagePathCallback = null
                cameraImagePath = null
    
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    getString(R.string.cannot_open_file_chooser_txt),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
    
                return false
            }
    
            return true
        }

        private fun createImageCaptureIntent(): Intent? {
            var captureImageIntent: Intent? = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    
            if (captureImageIntent?.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                var imageFile: File? = null
    
                try {
                    imageFile = createImageFile()
                    captureImageIntent.putExtra("CameraImagePath", cameraImagePath)
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }
    
                if (imageFile != null) {
                    cameraImagePath = CAMERA_PHOTO_PATH_POSTFIX + imageFile.absolutePath
                    captureImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile))
                } else {
                    captureImageIntent = null
                }
            }
    
            return captureImageIntent
        }
    
        private fun createImageFile(): File? {
            val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(Date())
            val imageFileName = PHOTO_NAME_POSTFIX + timeStamp + "_"
            val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    
            return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, PHOTO_FORMAT, storageDir)
        }
```

Implement `onRequestPermissionsResult` in your `Activity`

```
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.amera_permission_granted_txt),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    getString(R.string.camera_permission_denied_txt),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Implement `onActivityResult` in your `Activity`

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode != REQUEST_SELECT_FILE || imagePathCallback == null) return

    var results: Array<Uri>? = null

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            if (cameraImagePath != null) results = arrayOf(Uri.parse(cameraImagePath))
        } else {
            val dataString = data.dataString
            if (dataString != null) results = arrayOf(Uri.parse(dataString))
        }
    }

    imagePathCallback?.onReceiveValue(results)
    imagePathCallback = null
}
```

Constants

```
companion object {
    private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 113
    private const val REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 13
    private const val INTENT_FILE_TYPE = "image/*"
    private const val CAMERA_PHOTO_PATH_POSTFIX = "file:"
    private const val PHOTO_NAME_POSTFIX = "JPEG_"
    private const val PHOTO_FORMAT = ".jpg"
}
```

Try and see, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**Did you grant Camera permission into your WebView's WebChromeClient?**

Please add camera permission into your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
```

Set WebChromeClient into your WebView.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new ChromeClient())
```

Define the your ChromeClient class.

```
public class ChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (!hasPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                checkStoragePermission();
                return false;
            }
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select Photo");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, Constant.INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;

        }
    }
```

Here are variables.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
```

Check the storage and camera permission.

```
 private void checkStoragePermission() {
        String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, Constant.REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            checkCameraPermission();
        }
    }

    private void checkCameraPermission() {
        String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, Constant.REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            onPermissionGranted();
        }
    }
```

After that, I can access to camera and gallery.

Hope it to be helpful.

Comment: that works well for me but after that I'm not able to get the picture back from the camera!
any help please?

Answer (score 1):

For Android 10, SDK 30

Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in application tag in manifest

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65415381/7775500

this might help you ..

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem too. I will share it with others who are likely to have this problem in the future.

You must have the **camera permission** in the **manifest** and grant it in the `onPermissionRequest` methode in your `WebChromeClient` and be sure to set `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to **false** in the **webView setting**.

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Add this in webView setting:

```
binding.webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

And grant the permission in **onPermissionRequest**  methode:

```
@Override
public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
    request.grant(requestedResources);
}
```

for more information see this link:

[StackOverFlow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609282/12980812)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31119312)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need the permissions to open the camera on android.

Edit the manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

You might also need a library not included